# Are these "not only...but..."structures right or wrong and why?

Tags: comparative-constructions, formal-language

I have been taught that the same parts of speech should be used in "not only..but...". However, Vanessa used these examples and I was puzzled.

Example 1.

> It is not only difficult to find a good time, but it is also hard to find a good teacher.

Example 2.

> English helps me not only get a good job, but it also helps me connect with other people.

I am wondering whether the following sentence is right:

> The success of entrepreneurs not only creates fortune, but it is also good for the country.

Comment: Who is 'Vanessa'?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffcm&q=Vanessa+used+these+examples+and+I+was+puzzled.&ia=web

Comment: https://www.dictionarybook.org/sentence/vanessa.html

Comment: _English helps me not only [to] get a good job, but also [to] connect with other people._ It's unnecessary to repeat _it helps me_.

Answer (score 1):

Those sentences all read quite naturally to me, and I could imagine a native speaker saying them both in normal unprepared rapid speech, or in non-professional or non-academic writing. We easily understand what they mean, and it doesn't sound wrong at all.

But in formal writing, all three of your example sentences are mistakes, and look sloppy and unprofessional. A good editor would spot and fix these.